# How to map PowerOff button as End on XWindows?

Tags: ubuntu, key-mapping

I have this unfortunate PowerOff button on my laptop situated in the place of the End key: [image: ASUS G551JM]

I already [have a way to disable the PowerOff handler triggered by the OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580902/how-to-change-mapping-for-the-poweroff-key-on-keyboard/580904?noredirect=1#comment803248_580904) (Ubuntu 14.04 in my case). Now I want to do something useful with it, like using it as an `end` key.

The key presses for the PowerOff are handled by the *Power Button* device, as opposed to all the other keys (including the `End`), which are handled by usual `AT Translated Set 2 keyboard`:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I guess it would make re-mapping a little more difficult, but I believe it is still doable.

Furthermore, the key presses for the `PowerOff` are only partially visible for the X Window system, i.e. without the `KeyRelease` and `KeyPress` events:

```
$xev
...
KeymapNotify event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
...
```

Which I guess prevents me from assigning them using Ubuntu's own keyboard shortcut manager:

[image]

The key gets assigned just fine on the UI. The problem is that the action is never fired when it is pressed. And I don't want to run a command - I want the system to interpret this key as another `end` key.

And this is basically as far as I got.